# Indentation not correctly done when adding some json text into the pdf file

Tags: c#, .net, pdfsharpcore

I have some troubles with PDFSharpcore. I would integrate some json text, created with NewtonSoft.json (vers 13.0.3), into a pdf file and to indent it correctly. The text is correctly integrated into the pdf file but the indentation is replaced by some white squares, as if the writer did not understand the indentation. I tried several encoding but it didn't change anything.

the json text is correctly integrated into the pdf file generated. But the indentation is not done and is replaced by some white squares. I would generate a pdf file with a json text correctly indented.

I am using PDFSharpCore vers 1.3.62 with .NET 5.

Can I have some help please ?

Comment: Have you checked how the indentation of the json is done before all the pdf steps? Whitespaces, Tabs, "special whitespaces" etc.

Comment: Hello @ralf . Thanks for your help. I use JsonConvert.Serialize with the option Formatting.Indent to make the json.